# VB.net Pageant scoring system

Tags: sql, vb.net, pageant

I'm an I.T. student creating a pageant scoring system using VB.net and Microsoft SQL for database.
I'm wondering what method to implement on how to connect the ADMIN's server to multiple judges' nodes.

I have already constructed some GUI, and already normalized the database.
I have searched the winsock method but I'm planning to use this system on different nodes, so, this can be troublesome to modify every time I use it to other nodes.

I have searched that it is possible to connect them through ad hoc, but I don't know how to start it.

So, please enlighten me on this method. Thank you

.......
it's more like this.

1 sql server database sitting on a drive that all clients & server can see
1 system sitting on each client/judge machine, connecting to this sql database
1 system sitting on the server/admin machine, connected to the same database.
the client software inputs score to tables
the server-side software refreshes everytime someone entered their score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your software should connect using a single non-adminstrator account. You do not have to create a different account on SQL Server for each different user in your software.

Regarding the connection method, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "different nodes".

Comment: My answer is far from complete. You should try to ask a specific and clear question regarding the handling of users in a software. I still don't understand what you mean about the "nodes"